# Backbone - overriding sync using Prototype not assigning values

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototype, fetch

I am very new to backbone.js and was trying to add custom headers by overriding sync method.

```
(function(sync){
Backbone.Model.prototype.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    return sync(method, model, $.extend(true, {
        headers: //custom header here
    }, options));
};})(Backbone.Model.prototype.sync);
```

This seems to be only working when I remove the Model.Prototype. Can someone please explain why I am not able to override the prototype method here?

Comment: i believe that you loose a context inside your sync

Comment: actually i do not recomment do it like this. you can change Backbone.ajax instead

Comment: and if i was you and i really need this sync i will change it not in a vendor prototype. BaseMode = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `sync()` try `sync.call(this, arguments)`